# Active Directory Searchable Filters

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to query a company's active directory server to get a list of searchable attributes?

I am a novice w.r.t. to AD but I do know that some common searchable attributes are:

- Common Name
- Distinguished Name
- Organizational Unit

But, some companies may choose not to use some of these fields and others may use fields that are not in the above list.

The problem I am trying to solve is to offer the customer a list of searchable attributes from their AD installation and allow them to specify search filters to narrow down the list of users or groups to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LDAP you can get all possible attributes from the scubschema entry of the rootDSE.

You first need to query like:

```
ldapsearch -s base -b "" -D cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com -w 'password' -x -h 192.168.3.10 objectClass=* subschemasubentry

Which returns
dn: subschemaSubentry: CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Then a query like:

```
ldapsearch -s base -b "CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com" -D cn=Administrator,dc=domain,dc=com -w password -x -h 192.168.3.11  objectclass=subschema attributetypes
```

Will return ALL the attributes. This will be ALL the attributes weather or not they have values or not. 
-jim